debugging configuration of dap in nvim for typescipt projects
I am currently unable to find a debbugging configuration for ndap that works for my setup.
The typescript setup is straight forward. tsc transpiles to the /dist folder and the entry point is the dist/index.js file
I have read through numerous guides and been trying to find a solution online but nothing worked. I am using nixvim but the setup is just lua. I have been able to set up javascript without any problems so the nodeJs <-> debugger connection works without a problem. However if I try typescript the application just runs through without hitting any breakpoints.
My guess is that there is something preventing the source maps from being registered correctly however I do not see any error messages. Also the usual launch.json files to work in vscode without any problems. Here is my current config (one of many I have tried)
-- ...
      local js_based_languages = {
        "typescript",
        "javascript",
        "vue" 
      };

      dap_vscode_js.setup({
        adapters = { 'pwa-node', 'pwa-chrome', 'pwa-msedge', 'node-terminal', 'pwa-extensionHost' }
      })


      -- DEBUG CONFIG
      for _, language in ipairs(js_based_languages) do

        dap.configurations[language] = {
          {
            type = "pwa-node",
            request = "launch",
            name = "new launch",
            program = "index.js",
            cwd = "''${workspaceFolder}/dist",
          },
          -- ...
        }
      end
-- ...

I also worked with program being *dist/index.js" and the default cwd being the workspaceFolder. I have experimented with all kinds of values for outFiles or resolveSourceMapLocations. I have explicitly set sourceMaps to true. All with the same outcome.

ok so I found out that the problem does not seem to be the dap configuration itsself but  that the first file encountered gets processed to quickly. if I just use a timeout somewhere for a few milliseconds debugging works. maybe because otherwise the maps are not processed in time? Any config with the debugger itself that could be the problem?
